# Why is there no search option on a user's tags?

Tags: feature-request, search

Suppose that I'm searching for one of my old answers, I could find the answer by guessing the tags, and then clicking that tag on my profile (which gives a list of your questions/answers associated with that tag).

It's pretty easy to find the tag if I'm having a small collection of tags associated with my profile, but if the tags list becomes big it felt a little hard to find out the specific tag from my entire list of tags.

Right now I search like this:

`user:me [tag]` to get all my posts with a particular `tag`, but what if I'm not sure about what the `tag` is (sometimes hard to remember `tags` which are not that widely used)?

In this case having a search option may list only possible tags.

*Will it be possible to have a tag search option or is there any other existing ways to achieve this which I didn't notice?*

See the below image.

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly what the search result to be? If you search on your tag page for `andr` you want to list all tags which contain those letters?

Comment: @rene yes exactly

Answer (score 5):

That functionality doesn't exist but you can use the following runable Stack Snippet to achieve what you're looking for. I leave it to you to convert this in a userscript if you want that to be available on your own userpage.

The stack snippet calls the [`/users/{ids}/tags`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-on-users#order=desc&sort=popular&ids=8009433&filter=!bNKX0pggz8s7xt&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint that is available in the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('go');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var terms = document.getElementById('terms');
var user = document.getElementById('user');

function tdDate(seconds) {
    function pad(s) {
      return ('0' + s.toString()).substr(-2);
    }

    var dtm = new Date(seconds * 1000);
    return td(dtm.getFullYear() + '-' +
       pad(dtm.getMonth()) + '-' +
       pad(dtm.getDate()) + ' ' +
       pad(dtm.getHours()) + ':' + 
       pad(dtm.getMinutes()));
}

function td(value) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML = value;
  return td;
}

function addTag(item) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild(td(item.name));
    tr.appendChild(td(item.count));
    tr.appendChild(tdDate(item.last_activity_date));
    return tr;
}

function handleResponse(items) {
  items.forEach((i) => {
    if (i.name && i.name.indexOf(terms.value) > -1) {
      result.appendChild(addTag(i));
    }
  });
}

function load(page, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', url + '&page=' + page);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function(data) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (parsed.items) handleResponse(parsed.items);
    if (parsed.has_more === true) {
      setTimeout(() => {load(page + 1, url);}, (parsed.backoff ||0) * 1000);
    }
  });
  xhr.send();
}

function search() {
  while(result.firstChild) {
    result.removeChild(result.firstChild);
  }

 load(1, 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/'+  user.value +'/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow&filter=!bNKX0pggz8s7xt');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => search());
```

```css
label {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div#search div {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <div>
    <label>User:</label>
    <input type="text" id="user" value="8009433" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="terms" value="android" />
  </div>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <button id="go">Search</button>
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> tag </th>
        <th> count </th>
        <th> last_active </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="result">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @MMAdams do you like my userscript?